# Order By before Group By using Eloquent (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a "messages" table with the following columns

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fromId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `toId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `device` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=57 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I'm trying to get all messages where 'toId' = $id and grouping by fromId. The problem is that the "message" shown on the results is the first ones, not the latest ones. I tried ordering by createdAt but it's not working.

How can I order by "createdAt" prior to querying and grouping the results? I want to do this in the laravel way using Eloquent.

My query:

```
$chats = Message::with('sender','recipient')
        ->where('toId',$id)
        ->orderBy('createdAt')
        ->groupBy('fromId')
        ->paginate(10)
```

Comment: Can you maybe show us what your query in Eloquent looks like now? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I updated the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found a way to do that! Basically, creating a subquery and running it before, so that results are ordered as expected and grouped after.

Here is the code:

```
$sub = Message::orderBy('createdAt','DESC');

$chats = DB::table(DB::raw("({$sub->toSql()}) as sub"))
    ->where('toId',$id)
    ->groupBy('fromId')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 51):

I just needed to do something similar with a messages model. What worked for me was applying the `unique` method on the returned eloquent collection.

```
Model::where('toId', $id)
    ->orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
    ->get()
    ->unique('fromId');
```

The query will return all messages ordered by `createdAt` and the `unique` method will reduce it down to one message for each `fromId`. This is obviously not as performant as using the database directly, but in my case I have further restrictions on the query.

Also, there are many more useful methods for working with these collections: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#available-methods

Comment: You just saved me!

Comment: That is great. It is very helpful for me

Comment: gracias . . . .

Comment: Not useful if the output is limited. In that case, the result count will vary.

Answer (score 10):

Try this query :

```
$chats = Message::with('sender','recipient')
->where('toId',$id)
->whereRaw('id IN (select MAX(id) FROM messages GROUP BY fromId)')
->orderBy('createdAt','desc')
->paginate(10)
```

Answer (score 5):

It should be something along this:

```
Message::whereToId($id)->groupBy('fromId')->latest('createdAt')->first();
```

**Update**

After seeing the query that you've added, you probably just need to add a direction to the `orderBy` function, like this:

```
$chats = Message::with('sender','recipient')
    ->select(DB::raw('*, max(createdAt) as createdAt'))
    ->where('toId',$id)
    ->orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
    ->groupBy('fromId')
    ->paginate(10)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but when I do like this, the message field shows the first message of the group. I want to show the latest one (ordered by createdAt or ID DESC).

Comment: I updated my answer again based on the query that you added to your question.

Comment: That really doesn't work. The orderBy is run after the group, so it will order the groups, not the records inside the group.. you got it? I think I need to orderby first and group after, but laravel doesn't seem to allow me to choose to do this.

Comment: Ah, yes, it's more of a limitation of how the MySQL orderBy and groupBy functions work. To work around it, you need to select the max value of the column you want to order by. I've update the query. I hope this helps you out.

Comment: That's just the way group by works.  Each `fromId` has multiple `createdAt`s so it's not dependable to order by that column.  Instead of `orderBy`, try `orderByRaw('max(createdAt) desc')`.

Comment: I tried both solutions: select with DB::RAW and orderByRaw. Both return the first message in the group. The orderBy is run after (when results are already grouped in the ASCending order).

Comment: Hmm, I think you may be misunderstanding the goal of `groupBy`, as this will effectively return only one row per `fromId`. Is that not what you are after?

Comment: This table shows all messages that the recipient (toId) received from other users (fromId). I want to return one record per sender (fromId), and this is indeed working. Basically, grouping by fromId will show one message per sender (fromId). BUT, the record choosen by MySQL is the first record for that sender and I want the latest record (so I get the latest message that user sent). Your solution is grouping correctly, but each group shows the first message from the user, not the latest.

Answer (score 2):

This work for me:
(you can remove the order by createdAt in case createAt increase along with id)

```
DB::select(DB::raw('select * from (select * from messages group by fromId desc) m order by m.createdAt'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $data = MCCAddMilkEntry::where('coming_from','=','society')
        ->whereRaw('id = (select max(`id`) from mcc_add_milk_entry)')->get();
```

Comment: Try This , Working For Me

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score 0):

@Sergio your answer is good but what if someone wanted to select a related model along with....?

Answer : I have tested every single function but I didn't fetch the correct data.
`unique()` gives data with associated array.
`groupBy()` gives better but picking first message.

Solution for Latest inbox messages. My case:

```
$data = ChatMessage::where('incoming_msg_id', auth()->user()->id)->orWhere('outgoing_msg_id', auth()->user()->id)->latest('msg_id')->with('messageable')->get();
    $inbox = [];
    $itemIds = [];
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if (!in_array($value['messageable_id'].$value['msg_for'], $itemIds)) {
            array_push($inbox,$value);
            array_push($itemIds,$value['messageable_id'].$value['msg_for']);
        }
    }
    return $this->sendResponse($inbox,'Inbox');
```

Your case:

```
$chats = Message::where('toId',$id)->orWhere('fromId', $id)->latest('id')->with('sender','recipient')->get();
    $inbox = [];
    $fromIds = [];
    foreach ($chats as $key => $value) {
        if (!in_array($value['fromId'], $fromIds)) {
            array_push($inbox,$value);
            array_push($fromIds,$value['fromId']);
        }
    }
    return $this->sendResponse($inbox,'Inbox');
```