# Subquery with eloquent model in laravel 5

Tags: sql, laravel-5

I have the following raw query:

```
select * 
from (select * from settings order by priority desc) x
group by name
```

I would like to use a laravel 5 query builder instead but cant get the subquery to work. Is there a way to do this without using raw query's?

The table:

```
id - name - priority
1    1      1
2    1      2
3    2      1
```

In the above case It will return row 2 and 3 like I want to

I tried this query:

```
$settings = \App\Setting::where('user_id', Auth::id())->orWhere('tool_id', $id)->groupBy('name')->orderBy('priority', 'desc')->get();
```

But this will return row 1 and 3.

Comment: that makes no sense, just use the subselect. there's no reason to group by name as you're not aggregating any other fields

Comment: @RichBenner I editted my post for some more clarity

Comment: try Query Builder instead of Eloquent like in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31864088/3018183

Answer (score 1):

Can you use CTE expressions? RANK() would work:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT *, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY priority desc) AS RowRank 
  FROM settings
)
SELECT id, name, priority
FROM CTE c
WHERE c.RowRank = 1
```

Comment: The query already works. I just want to convert it into a query builder but no luck on that