# Laravel count, groupBy and orderBy not working properly

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, read-unread

This is the structure of my table
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmgtJ.png

**Users Table**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abid |

**Messages Table**

| id | user_id | to_user | content | read |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | message | 0 |

I want to show notifications for users like **User1 send you messages (24)** here 24 is the total unread messages of user1.

**Problem**: Notification must be shown in this order. The user that sends messages recently will show first. It is exactly the problem that I have to face.

**Output Example**: like the android app **WhatsApp** show a message in the chat area.

**Note**: read column type Boolean also added in the messages table.

Note: **In this application only users and admin will chat with each other.**

Looking for elegant Laravel 8 queries that give me results.

Comment: Welcome! Please show your code and what you have tried. And screenshots are frowned upon.

Comment: Thank you. I have posted the code as an answer please check it.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution.**

Finally, I have found a solution by review these links I want to appreciate those people by giving links to their answers.

1. [GroupBy after orderBy for complicated query in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39052629/groupby-after-orderby-for-complicated-query-in-laravel)
2. [Order By before Group By using Eloquent (Laravel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31857961/order-by-before-group-by-using-eloquent-laravel)
3. [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column/7745635#7745635)

**Here is the final code**

```
$result= Message::with('users')
         ->select(DB::raw('id,from_user,to_user,created_at, max(created_at) as createdAt'))
         ->where('to_user',$user)
         ->orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
         ->groupBy('from_user')
         ->selectRaw('count(messages.from_user) as total_msg')
         ->get();
```

**And here is the final result**

[Final Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgnZW.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
$message = DB::table('message')->select('message.user_id');

/* join */
$message = $message->join('user', 'message.to_user', '=', 'user.id');    

/* select statements */
$message = $message->addSelect('message.to_user');
$message = $message->addSelect(DB::raw('COUNT(*) AS total_messages'));

$message = $message->groupBy('message.user_id', 'message.to_user');
$message = $message->get();
```

This should count how many messages that user sent to another user(s).

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cbcee2/1)

Comment: I have modified your query slightly.

Comment: I am posting in the next answer please check and give me suggestions.

Comment: You need to order by `DESC` method and by default order by use `ASC` method.

Comment: This should work:

`$result = $message->orderBy('messages.created_at', 'DESC')->get();`

Comment: Thank you so much, dear. I have found a solution. I am posting it as an answer.

Comment: Don’t mention it.