# laravel group by fetch latest record from table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have one table where I want to retrieve data group by the user but I want the latest entry in result how can I do that by using eloquent.

here is an eloquent query I am using.

```
Product::whereNotNull('user_id')
         ->orderBy('id','desc')
         ->groupBy('user_id')
         ->get();
```

here is my table

```
Id   Name   user_id
-------------------------
1    A       1
2    b       1
3    c       2
4    d       2
5    e       3
6    f       3
```

result my query is giving me

```
Id   Name   user_id
-------------------------
1    A       1
3    c       2
5    e       3
```

result i want

```
Id   Name   user_id
-------------------------
2    b       1
4    d       2
6    f       3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order By before Group By using Eloquent (Laravel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31857961/order-by-before-group-by-using-eloquent-laravel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Product::whereRaw('id IN (select MAX(id) FROM products GROUP BY user_id)')
         ->whereNotNull('user_id')
         ->orderBy('id','desc')
         ->get();
```

You will need a nested query for that, i don't think you can avoid it but this solution should work.

`GroupBy` happens before `OrderBy` so you have to get your last record before you do your ordering

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$subquery = Product::orderBy('id','DESC');

$products = DB::table(DB::raw("({$subquery->toSql()}) as subquery"))
   ->whereNotNull('user_id')
   ->groupBy('user_id')
   ->get();
```

2nd way : use `unique()` method in collection (The `unique` method returns all of the unique models in the collection):

```
$products = Product::whereNotNull('user_id')
             ->orderBy('id','desc')
             ->get()
             ->unique('user_id');
```

Comment: hey, Yasin, your first solution worked but not returned eloquent object and the second solution is not working......

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)

**latest / oldest**

The `latest` and `oldest` methods allow you to easily order results by date. By default, result will be ordered by the `created_at` column. Or, you may pass the column name that you wish to sort by:

```
$product = Product::latest()->first();
```