# Laravel Group By and Order By not working

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, fetch

I tried to make a Laravel 5.8 project, and the data in the project is like this :

```
id  |purch| name         |  prcvalue
------------------------------------
1   |10234| Nabila       | 100
2   |10234| Nadeera      | 450
3   |10234| Nabila       | 540
4   |10234| Nadeera      | 480
```

then i need to show that data like this :

```
id  |purch| name         |  prcvalue
------------------------------------
3   |10234| Nabila       | 540
4   |10234| Nadeera      | 480
```

I have tried using `GroupBy = name` and `OrderBy prcvalue DESC` but it just return :

```
id  |purch| name         |  prcvalue
------------------------------------
1   |10234| Nabila       | 100
2   |10234| Nadeera      | 450
```

does anyone know how i can get the results that i need?
here my code :

```
myModel::where('purch','=','10234')
      ->orderBy('prcvalue','DESC')
      ->groupBy('name')
      ->get();
```

many thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order By before Group By using Eloquent (Laravel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31857961/order-by-before-group-by-using-eloquent-laravel)

Comment: Looks like a simple greatest n per group problem.

Comment: @YasinPatel ,thank you but its not answer my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need max value ,

```
  myModel::select('id','purch','name',DB::raw("MAX(prcvalue) as prcvalue"))
  ->where('purch','=','10234')
  ->orderBy('prcvalue','DESC')
  ->groupBy('name')
  ->get();
```

And if it still not working , edit in config/database.php.
In mysql array , set to  strict => false

Comment: well this works, i get highest prcvalue, but the id that showing is not the id of the higest prcvalue, the id must be "3" not "1" , many thanks

Comment: I just give you another advice , firstly you should select out max value of prcvalue and then you get data by where in max prcvalue . In this way , you perhet no need group by.

Comment: Or how about groupBy('id')

Answer (score 3):

If You want the latest id of records then you can use unique() after get(), don't use group by if you use groupBy then you lose your control from id. I hope this is useful for you

```
myModel::select('id','purch','name','prcvalue')
  ->where('purch','=','10234')
  ->orderBy('prcvalue','DESC')
  ->get()
  ->unique('name');
```