# Laravel/MySQL change groupBy sort order? Or group by latest id, not first found

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have `attempts` table with following data:

```
ID | ATTEMPT_NO | LESSON_ID | TEST_ID | VALID
---------------------------------------------------------
76 |    123     |     3     |    4    |   0
77 |    123     |     3     |    9    |   1
```

I need to group data by attempt_no, and if possible get latest value from group.

My code:

```
Attempts::groupBy('attempt_no')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

Problem is, groupBy takes first found record. If:

ID: **76**; VALID = **1**;

ID: **77**; VALID = **0**;

// query returns valid **true**

Hovewer if

ID: **76**; VALID = **0**;

ID: **77**; VALID = **1**;

// query returns valid **false**;

I tried all possible combinations including:

```
Attempts::groupBy('attempt_no')->orderBy('valid', 'desc')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10); // not what I need

Attempts::orderBy('valid', 'desc')->groupBy('attempt_no')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10); // not what I need
```

But any of my attempt returns result which I need, that's why I am asking here for help.

---

UPDATE: Solved by myself, maybe somebody will need it:

```
$my_solutions = Attempts::whereRaw('id = (SELECT max(id) FROM attempts a2 WHERE a2.attempt_no = attempts.attempt_no)')
            ->groupBy('attempt_no')
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Glad you solved it, if you have an answer, [post it as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).  There are many similar questions here already, ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31857961/order-by-before-group-by-using-eloquent-laravel)) if they answer your question, consider [closing this one as a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates).